# CloudWatch logs with Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am upgrading my Elastic Beanstalk environment to use Amazon Linux 2.

In my old environment, I could monitor my Spring Boot application logs by watching the log group using cw.exe /aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log

Now, however, no logs are displayed for the new application, and furthermore I notice that the stdouterr.log in /eb-current-app/ seems to prepend the instance ID of the log.

What do I need to do restore the previous behavior so I can monitor my logs?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Answer (score 2):

Cloudwatch logs is available as a yum package now in Amazon Linux 2:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

```
sudo yum install -y awslogs
```

You might have to edit this file `/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf` too to change the region.

Finally you will need to start and enable

```
sudo systemctl start awslogsd
sudo systemctl enable awslogsd.service
```

And set it all up as a [config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in this file `ebextensions/cloudwatch.config`

Comment: Very helpful. I was trying to figure out why some of our startup commands were failing even though the package was installed, on our migration from AL1 to Al2, and it looks like the binary name changed from `awslogs` to `awslogsd`.

Comment: Yes there are unfortunately a bunch of subtle 1->2 changes, that can easily derail your conversion.